# SMS verification code request failed when authenticating using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, sms-retriever-api

When authenticating using Firebase Auth, I want to auto input the code that is received via SMS. I am able to receive SMS and go through auth process manually, but when I use SmsRetriever, the app crashes and then the bottom sheet dialog shows up.
This is everything that that appears in Logcat:

> E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17010 null

Code in Fragment where user inputs their phone number:

```
private val SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST = 2  // Set to an unused request code

    private val smsVerificationReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
                val extras = intent.extras
                val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

                when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                        // Get consent intent
                        val consentIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                        try {
                            // Start activity to show consent dialog to user, activity must be started in
                            // 5 minutes, otherwise you'll receive another TIMEOUT intent
                            startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                            // Handle the exception ...
                        }
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                        // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val task = SmsRetriever.getClient(requireActivity()).startSmsUserConsent(null)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        requireActivity().registerReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver, intentFilter)
    }
    
    override fun sendSms() {
        showProgressBar(true)
        SmsRetriever.getClient(requireActivity()).startSmsUserConsent(presenter.getNumber())
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(presenter.getNumber())
            .setTimeout(58L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(requireActivity())
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        requireContext().unregisterReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver)
    }
```

This is the code in Fragment where user has to input the code:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            // ...
            SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST ->
                // Obtain the phone number from the result
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    // Get SMS message content
                    val message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
                    // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                    // `message` contains the entire text of the SMS message, so you will need
                    // to parse the string.
                    message?.let { presenter.parseSms(it) }
                    // send one time code to the server
                } else {
                    // Consent denied. User can type OTC manually.
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Print your FirebaseAuthException error to see what's going on. If you're using a real phone number for development and using it again and again, Firebase might block the device for a time being.

SOLUTION: Add a test phone number with a password and use it.

Answer (score 3):

try to print exception in onFailure like --> {p0.message} print this line logcat and it will definately show -->   E/exception in firebase: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later. this is why because we are using this phone number many times for login

Answer (score 1):

It is a too-many-request error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfPyx.jpg)

The solution is to either wait for few hours or -if this user is a test user- , just add the number in test users to fix the code and do not send too many SMSes.

Answer (score 0):

It came up with simple solution for me to add SHA1 and SHA-256 key to my firebase Console